# Where to find NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, android-support-library, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to use a NestedScrollView in Eclipse. However, each time my app crashes with a "Class Not Found" error.

Everything I see online says it belongs in `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`. However, I have the `android.support.v4` jar in my libs and it is correctly included (I can use other classes from there). However, when I expand it out, `NestedScrollView` is not part of the jar.

Where can I find a jar to allow me to use NestedScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

`android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` was introduced in version 22.1.0 of Support libraries [as mentioned here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) and is available for most of android versions (see support library minSdk, they increase it time to time. it's 14 for 26.0.0)

it is located in support-core-ui library (which is downloaded as dependency with support-v4, you don't need to specify it explicitly if you use gradle/maven/ant)

If you are downloading and including jars manually, consider moving to gradle, because most of libraries have dependencies on others which is handled automatically and saves you time. Also many of android libraries are .aar, not .jar. Adding aars manually is harder and, again will be handled automatically by gradle (or maven, or ant, but gradle is most used for android development i.e. most supported)

Answer (score -1):

NestedScrollView was introduced in Android from 22.1.0. So ensure that you are using at least that AppCompat Library.

PS : Please start using Android Studio for development. People have been using it since 2014. It is high time you move to that environment. And specifically for your question, Studio would have warned you about which version to use.

Comment: I would love to use Android Studio, unfortunately, Eclipse is still required by my work for certain projects due to things I can't affect. I know how easy it is to add in for Studio. How would I ensure that for Eclipse? I'm aware of setting the min and build apis (they are above 22) and I've added the jars to the build path. However, it still can't seem to find the class.